# Is my code for changing the resolution correct?

Tags: grass-gis, grass.script, shell, msys

I have a raster files of daily minimum temperature (tmin) for the period 1962-2011 at a resolution of 1.125. I need to convert each single day raster file into 0.5 using inverse distance interpolation. The file is for the entire world and I need the file only for a selected county.

```
g.region vect=my_location  # setting g. region to my area of interest
i=1962                      #beginning of loop  
while [ $i != 2011 ]
do
    j=1
    while [ $j != 366 ]
    do
            g.region res=1.125                   #original resolution
            r.to.vect input=tmin$i.$j output=point_tmin$i_$j feature=point      #converts raster to point 
            g.region res=0.5                # changes the resolution
            v.surf.idw input=point_tmin$i_$j output=idw_tmin$i.$j column=value npoints=4            #does the interpolation
            g.remove vec=point_tmin$i_$j
            j=`expr $j + 1`
   done
   i=`expr $i + 1`
done
```

I just need a confirmation from someone if this code will work fine and will do the desired work. I ran it only for a single file and then tried to make a shell script to run it for all the files.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Well, technically it looks OK, but your are aware that you'll be creating almost 20,000 (!) rasters maps. Is that what you want??

You do not need to reset the resolution back to 1.125 at the start of each loop.

Also, if all you want is to set a smaller resolution, why not try r.resample? It uses nearest neighbor, not IDW, but it might be good enough in this case.

Comment: Yes this is what I want. I am not sure about the resampling thing. The end result is that for my location, I want to extract tmin of each 0.5 grid and that is why I wanted to convert the resolution from 1.125 to 0.5 and then print tmin of each 0.5 grid. So do you think if I print out the tmin of map/s produced by this code, they will be for each grid whose spatial resolution is 0.5 (~ 55 km)?

Comment: The minimum temperature of the resampled grid (using IDW) will not be any lower than the minimum temperature on the original grid--and if the two minima differ (which they are likely to do) that would be an artifact of the IDW method, anyway. Thus, if you just need minimum temperatures, all this work of resampling not only is useless but actually makes the results less accurate.

Comment: Thanks a lot.I realise that the results will be the same and any difference would be because of IDW. I am keeping this point in my mind and would mention this in my report. Thanks a lot for this anyway.